# Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have two Dictionaries: A, B
The keys are progressive numbers from 0 to 1000.
The value can be none(empty) or some digit (max 8 digits)

**EX.**

```
A = {"0":"100","1":"32","2":"89827","3":"12345", "4":"12345"}  
B = {"0":"",   "1":"3", "2":"8827", "3":"12385", "4":"1535"}
```

I want to find if there are differences in the values of "B" respect to "A", so in my example:

```
B[1] respect A[1] = missing one digit (2)  
B[2] respect A[2] = missing one digit (9)  
B[3] respect A[3] = one digit is different (8)  
B[4] respect A[4] = one digit is different (5) and missing one digit (3)
```

I try with wildcard but it doesn't found for missing values.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Show us what you've tried concretely please.

Comment: does it needs a regex?

Comment: How about `A.values() == B.values()`?

Comment: This requires more logic than a single regex... you are looking for a difftool

Comment: I wouldn't do this with regex either..

Comment: @Boldewyn I think thats on the right track. However, it doesn't really give him much more information other than **something** is/is not different.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `difflib.SequenceMatcher`, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will do what you ask:

```
import difflib

diff = {}
for k, a_value in A.items():
    b_value = B[k]
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=b_value, b=a_value)
    diff[k] = []
    for opcode, b_start, b_end, a_start, a_end in matcher.get_opcodes():
        a_range = a_value[a_start:a_end]
        b_range = b_value[b_start:b_end]
        if opcode == 'replace':
            diff[k].append("%s digit(s) are different (%s)" % (len(b_range), b_range))
        elif opcode == 'delete':
            diff[k].append("has an extra %s digit(s) (%s)" % (len(b_range), b_range))
        elif opcode == 'insert':
            diff[k].append("missing %s digit(s) (%s)" % (len(a_range), a_range))

for k in sorted(diff.keys()):
    print "B[%s] respect A[%s] = %s" % (k, k, diff[k] and " and ".join(diff[k]) or "no differences")
```

Output:

```
B[0] respect A[0] = missing 3 digit(s) (100)
B[1] respect A[1] = missing 1 digit(s) (2)
B[2] respect A[2] = missing 1 digit(s) (9)
B[3] respect A[3] = 1 digit(s) are different (8)
B[4] respect A[4] = missing 3 digit(s) (234) and has an extra 2 digit(s) (35)
```

It does not produce the exact output you've asked for, because the algorithm behind `difflib.SequenceMatcher` does not try to find minimal edit sequences, but hopefully it will do.

This can be seen in the result for the `A[4]` vs `B[4]`.

If you want the exact output you've asked for, you'll need to roll your own algorithm.